# Filtrar por fecha angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente `array`:

```
$scope.array = [
    {'fecha': "2017-01-01",
    "texto": "luis"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-01",
    "texto": "jorge"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-01",
    "texto": "daniel"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-02",
    "texto": "pedro"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-03",
    "texto": "crhis"},
    ];
```

el cual en mi vista `html` lo muestro de la siguiente manera:

```
<ul ng-repeat="i in array">
    <li>{{i.fecha}} {{i.texto}}</li>
 </ul>
```

pero el resultado de esto es:

```
2017-01-01 luis
2017-01-01 jorge
2017-01-01 daniel
2017-01-02 pedro
2017-01-03 crhis
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo filtrar por fecha, es decir que el resultado sea de la siguiente manera:

```
2017-01-01 -----> luis jorge daniel
2017-01-02 -----> pedro
2017-01-03 -----> crhis
```

en sí lo que quiero saber es cómo hacer el filtrado por fecha y que la fecha se muestre una sola vez juntos con sus datos.

Comment: en realidad lo que planteas no es filtrar la fechas sino agruparlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacer uso del filtro `groupBy` [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Agregas la referencia a `angular-filter.min.js` y el modulo como explica el titulo `Get Started`

Luego veras el ejemplo [groupBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) resuelve exactamente lo que buscas

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="player in value">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo una Excelente respuesta ...!

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el código funcionando de lo que pides, el secreto está en la lib. angular filter, dale ejecutar y pruebalo.

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.14/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div  ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in array | groupBy: 'fecha'">
    Fecha: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in value">
         {{ person.texto }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.array = [
    {'fecha': "2017-01-01",
    "texto": "luis"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-01",
    "texto": "jorge"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-01",
    "texto": "daniel"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-02",
    "texto": "pedro"},
    {'fecha': "2017-01-03",
    "texto": "crhis"},
    ];
});
</script>
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Es una excelente respuesta Amigo..!!

Comment: amigo como podria ordenar por fechas de forma descendente....!!! es decir por fechas 2017-01-03 ....... 2017-01-01

Comment: Puedes ordenarlo normal y aplicarle reverse deberia funcionar

Comment: filter:orderBy(array, expression[, reverse]);